# Calling a stored procedure from Hibernate using named parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a MS SQL Server stored procedure from Hibernate 4.3.5.Final using the org.hibernate.procedure.ProcedureCall interface using named parameters instead of positional parameters.  I have something like this:

```
ProcedureCall call = session.createStoredProcedureCall(procedureName);
call.registerParameter("parameter1Name", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(1);
call.registerParameter("parameter2Name", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(2);
call.getOutputs();
```

But I end up with this:

```
{call procedure_name (1, 2)};
```

instead of:

```
{call procedure_name (@parameter1Name = 1, @parameter2Name = 2)};
```

Note that there are no parameter names and the parameters are in exactly the order that they were specified.
NamedParameterRegistration inherits from AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl and doesn't override prepare().  For a parameter with a mode of IN or INOUT, it calls

```
typeToUse.nullSafeSet( statement, bind.getValue(), startIndex, session() );
```

which simply binds the parameter as an ordered parameter.

Is there something that I am missing, or is this just broken right now?

Comment: What error you are facing? post complete stacktrace.

Comment: I don't get an error, it just ignores the fact that the parameters are named and inserts them as if they were positional parameters.  See my example, I will add what it is supposed to execute.